# предача конфига tinymce в компонент vue.js

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть компонент

```
export default {
    Create() {
        this.loadInitialData();
    },
    data() {
        return {
            tinymceconfig: null,
            value: this.initialValue
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadInitialData() {
            axios.get('/tinymci/load').then((response) => {
                this.tinymceconfig = response.data.tinymceconfig;
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
    },
    props: {
        initialValue: {}
    },
    components: {
        'editor': Editor
    },
}
```

Шаблон компонента:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <editor name="company_history"
            :api-key="tinymceconfig.config.apikey"
            :init="tinymceconfig.config"
    >
    </editor>
  </div>
</template>
```

Превоначально прописал сам конфиг в data но потом решил перенести его в отдельный файл, в методах есть функция получения, она работает нормально, все возвращает как нужно, но в консоли выдает ошибки[image]
Насколько я понял vue рендерит шаблон, приходит в дату - смотрит что на null и выдает ошибку, но я запихивал вывод метода и в beforeCreate и в Create методы, они по идее прощитываются раньше чем шаблон отрендериться, в чем моя ошибка и как мне её поправить?

Comment: Нет, он пытается передать tinymceconfig а он null, или задайте ее или изначально задайте ему не null а пустой массив объект `tinymceconfig: {}`

Comment: @RuslanSemenov, задал, теперь он ругается на apikey of undefided, сделал вот так 
tinymceconfig: {
                    apikey:"",
                },
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apikey' of undefined"

Comment: так apikey у вас внутри конфига, поэтому `tinymceconfig: { config: {} }` Но вам проще сделать проверку и пока tinymceconfig не рендерить объект `<editor v-if="tinymceconfig"` И тогда можете оставить его как null изначально

Comment: @RuslanSemenov спасибо! помоголо!!!!